# How to get the first 4 words from a file in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to get the first 4 words from a file. These words can be separated by space, newline, carriage return or tab. So they can be all on the same line or on four different lines. Which method should I use? Thank you.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep reading words until you have at least four:

```
perl -e 'push @words, split " ", <> while (@words < 4);
         print "@words[0..3]\n";
        '
```

Comment: I assumed `split` will split the string using specified delimiter. In your code the delimiter is a space. Or `split` doesn't care if it is newline, cr etc.?

Comment: Read the documentation: [split](http://p3rl.org/split). Space is special, it means any whitespace.

Comment: @choroba Thanks for the advice. I didn't know the split " "` was for all whitespaces. It worked.